# How to Programmatically Disable Credentials Check Before Accessing Public AWS S3 Buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-credentials

My C++ program must access both public and private AWS buckets. The public buckets don’t belong to me so when the program tries to access them and my credentials are visible I get the following type errors:

```
Aws::S3::S3Errors::INVALID_ACCESS_KEY_ID    

"InvalidAccessKeyId"    

"The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records."
```

If I manually hide my credentials like this

`mv ~/.aws/credentials ~/.aws/credentials-hidden`

before running the program I can successfully list and get the public objects. But then, the program can't access my private buckets.

I’ve searched `S3Client` and `ClientConfiguration` for some option to disable and re-enable credentials checks but haven’t found it.

Please tell me how this is done.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cpp at all, but this maybe the way to go. http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_client_1_1_a_w_s_null_signer.html#af27021dfddc9152d0e19db478bc2d592

Comment: This sounds a little like the `--no-sign-request` option of the AWS CLI, but I don't know how to force it in a normal API call. The error message is very strange, because it should simply reject with a 403 rather than denying knowledge of the Access Key. I suggest you experiment with the AWS CLI to narrow-in on what might be happening, then implement your findings in your C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. To access public buckets without hiding my `~/.aws/credentials` file I can create an [S3Client](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_s3_1_1_s3_client.html#afbf33d6d257a997982d1a1b41eabec0a) with [empty credentials](http://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_auth_1_1_a_w_s_credentials.html#a266b4bef20a9c4a146dae2d93a8bd626).

```cpp
Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials empty_credentials { };
Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client { empty_credentials, config };
```